# Gitosis permissions issues

Tags: centos, permissions, git

I have Gitosis installed on a Centos box which I use to manage about a dozen repos(html/php/css etc) which I then manually pull through to live sites running on nginx/php as needed.

The issue I have is every time I do some work on one repository and then push my changes when I try and pull from another repo I get

ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:repository read access denied
Fatel: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I can however over come this by editing the gitosis.conf file and removing the offending repo then push, re-edit and reinstate the repo and push, then going back to the repo and I can work away pushing and pulling fine.

My question is this why would working on one repo disrupt another and why would changing the gitosis.conf as discribed above fix this only temporarily and not permanently.

I can manage it the way it is fine its just inconvenient to go round the houses every time I need to switch repo etc

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the gitosis.conf file on the server or in the gitosis-admin repository? Because the one that is on the server is actually generated from the one located in the repo, so you would need to change that one instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: always editing local version and then pushing to the server